# Atmel bootloader execution at start-up

Tags: bootloader, atmel

I'm using an ATmega328p microcontroller with the [optiboot](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot) bootloader.
Optiboot is configured to flash a "start LED" for 3 times when optiboot is running.

Fuse bits are set for a bootloader section of 256 words and BOOTRST is programmed to jump into the bootloader section at start-up.

With the bootloader installed, I flash the actual firmware via the UART (pin 30 and 31) and that all works fine.

**Now to my question:**

When my firmware is running and I pull the reset line of the atmel to GND, I can see the "start LED" flash 3 times and then the firmware execution starts. This tells me that the bootloader run right after the reset.
However, when I start-up the atmel (supply power to the chip), I do not see the "start LED" flash 3 times and the firmware code seems to be executed right away.

*Does anyone have an idea why optiboot flashes the "start LED" after pulling the reset line to GND and not when I power-on the chip?*

The reset line is directly connected with a 10k pullup to the supply voltage of the atmel.

I hope someone has an explanation and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You might get better answers on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

i think it's relevant ,

"On reset, Optiboot starts and reads the reset reason from MCUSR. For any cause other than "external reset", the application is started immediately. Otherwise, optiboot attempts to download new application software"